# Restore cursor position after :r

Tags: neovim

I have made a custom command, and I tried to use `mark` to save the cursor position. But the mark is set in the position where the file is inserted on the 6th line(using the `r` command).

```
vim.cmd [[ command! -nargs=1 Include call feedkeys("mx") | 6r <args> | call feedkeys("`x")]]
```

I think `6r <args>` is getting executed before `feedkeys("mx")`.Is there any way we can fix this?? or if there are other ways to restore cursor position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a "preserve cursor position" function in lua (neovim), it is in my utils.lua file, it goes like this:

```
M.preserve = function(arguments)
    local arguments = string.format("keepjumps keeppatterns execute %q", arguments)
    -- local original_cursor = vim.fn.winsaveview()
    local line, col = unpack(vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0))
    vim.api.nvim_command(arguments)
    local lastline = vim.fn.line("$")
    -- vim.fn.winrestview(original_cursor)
    if line > lastline then
        line = lastline
    end
    vim.api.nvim_win_set_cursor({ 0 }, { line, col })
end
```

The above function encapsules any give command, for example, if I want to reindent the whole file I create a Reindent command:

```
vim.cmd([[command! Reindent lua require('utils').preserve("sil keepj normal! gg=G")]])
```

And run:

```
:Reindent
```

To remove blank spaces at the end of any line:

```
vim.cmd([[cnoreab cls Cls]])
vim.cmd([[command! Cls lua require("utils").preserve('%s/\\s\\+$//ge')]])
```

Vimscript version of it:

```
" preserve function
if !exists('*Preserve')
    function! Preserve(command)
        try
            let l:win_view = winsaveview()
            "silent! keepjumps keeppatterns execute a:command
            silent! execute 'keeppatterns keepjumps ' . a:command
        finally
            call winrestview(l:win_view)
        endtry
    endfunction
endif
```

In my case I have another function to squeeze blank lines (if I have more than one consecutive blank like they become one), so, I have this function:

```
M.squeeze_blank_lines = function()
    -- references: https://vi.stackexchange.com/posts/26304/revisions
    if vim.bo.binary == false and vim.opt.filetype:get() ~= "diff" then
        local old_query = vim.fn.getreg("/") -- save search register
        M.preserve("sil! 1,.s/^\\n\\{2,}/\\r/gn") -- set current search count number
        local result = vim.fn.searchcount({ maxcount = 1000, timeout = 500 }).current
        local line, col = unpack(vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0))
        M.preserve("sil! keepp keepj %s/^\\n\\{2,}/\\r/ge")
        M.preserve("sil! keepp keepj %s/\\v($\\n\\s*)+%$/\\r/e")
        if result > 0 then
            vim.api.nvim_win_set_cursor({ 0 }, { (line - result), col })
        end
        vim.fn.setreg("/", old_query) -- restore search register
    end
end
```

Then I have the consecutive blank lines remove but the cursor remains where it is:

```
:nnoremap <leader>d :lua require('utils').squeeze_blank_lines()<cr>
```

Or if you are, by any chance using init.lua

```
-- map helper
local function map(mode, lhs, rhs, opts)
    local options = { noremap = true }
    if opts then
        options = vim.tbl_extend("force", options, opts)
    end
    vim.api.nvim_set_keymap(mode, lhs, rhs, options)
end

map("n", "<leader>d", '<cmd>lua require("utils").squeeze_blank_lines()<cr>')
```

I hope these ideas can help you to figure out a solution to your problem

A final tip: If you are using the proposed *utils.lua* you have to insert at the beginning of it:

```
local M = {}
```

and at the end of it:

```
return M
```

Comment: In your `preserve` function, I noticed that you included `if line > lastline then...`. In what circumstances does `vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0)` return a line number greater than the number of lines?

Comment: [mroavi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1706778/mroavi) When running the squeeze_blank_lines will change the number of lines, if you are at the end of the file, let's say line 50 and you have 4 repeated blank lines your last line will not be 50, hence throwing a error.

Comment: Can you comment on what the difference is between `api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0)` and `fn.pos(".")`? Is there any?

Comment: [Steven Lu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/340947/steven-lu) I think using the api is faster because it uses pure lua instead of vimscript, but I do not have enouth knowledge to explain more deeply.

Comment: Alternatively to checking that that old position is in bounds, you can use `vim.fn.cursor(position)` which does not raise any errors if the position is out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

This is converted from Vim defaults - `https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/defaults.vim#L105-L116`

```lua
-- When editing a file, always jump to the last known cursor position.
-- Don't do it when the position is invalid, when inside an event handler,
-- for a commit or rebase message
-- (likely a different one than last time), and when using xxd(1) to filter
-- and edit binary files (it transforms input files back and forth, causing
-- them to have dual nature, so to speak)
function RestoreCursorPosition()
  local line = vim.fn.line("'\"")
  if line > 1 and line <= vim.fn.line("$") and vim.bo.filetype ~= 'commit' and vim.fn.index({'xxd', 'gitrebase'}, vim.bo.filetype) == -1 then
    vim.cmd('normal! g`"')
  end
end

if vim.fn.has("autocmd") then
  vim.cmd([[
    autocmd BufReadPost * lua RestoreCursorPosition()
  ]])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For some read if you call `vim.fn.winsaveview()` immediately, it seems like it happens before the `do things` and the position is restored, well that's my theory.
To get `winrestview` to work, you have to delay it, either by using feed keys (yuck) or call it deferred with a small (e.g. 0) delay asynchronously:

```lua
vim.g.cursor_position = vim.fn.winsaveview()
-- do things
-- Now we restore the cursor position with a delay of 0ms
vim.defer_fn(function() vim.fn.winrestview(vim.g.cursor_position) end, 0)
```

Deferred keys version (not recommended, press <ctrl+v>then escape to insert a escape at the start of the string, and a CR at the end of the string (those sepcial chars were removed by stackoverflow):

```lua
vim.fn.feedkeys([[:lua vim.fn.winrestview(vim.g.cursor_position)]])
```